# JavaScript Local Time printing

Tags: javascript, localtime

Being a beginner, I'm facing some problems. Even I can't find any solution by googling it.

Problem: In my language (Bengali), the entire daytime has five strings ( Sokal, Dupur, Bikal, Sondha, Raat) instead of the international two strings(Am, Pm) .

I wrote this one, but didn't help me much.

```
    var time = new Date();

    var hour = time.getHours();
    var text = "sokal";

    if(hour == 13){
      text = "dupur";
    }else if(hour == 16){
      text = "bikal";
    }else if(hour == 18){
     text = "sondha"; 
    }else if(hour == 20){
      text = "raat"
    }

    console.log(text);
```

I want to print:

```
6Am to 11Am as 06:00 Sokal;
12Pm to 3pm as 12:00 Dupur;
4 Pm to 5Pm as 04:00 Bikal;
6 pm to 7pm as 06:00 Sondha;
8 pm to 5Am as 08:00 Raat;
```

Comment: Check for a range: `if(hour >= 12 && hour <= 15) text = "Dupur";` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be comparing the hour to different ranges, using [relational operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Relational_operators) like `<`, `>`, `<=`, or `>=`. For example, if the hour is less than 6, the period is `raat`.

Note also that you don't necessarily need to make two comparisons for each range. If the hour is *not* less than 6, you know it's greater than or equal to 7, so take advantage of the `else` to reduce the complexity of each subsequent `if`.

If I understand your requirements, it would look something like this:

```
function fmtPeriod(hour) {
  if (hour < 6) {
    return "Raat";
  } else if (hour < 12) {
    return "Sokal";
  } else if (hour < 16) {
    return "Dupur";
  } else if (hour < 18) {
    return "Bikal";
  } else if (hour < 20) {
    return "Sondha";
  } else {
    return "Raat"
  }
}
```

Precisely formatting dates can get pretty involved with different locale-specific rules, but again, based on what you've described, here's a stab at it:

```js
function fmtPeriod(hour) {
  if (hour < 6) {
    return "Raat";
  } else if (hour < 12) {
    return "Sokal";
  } else if (hour < 16) {
    return "Dupur";
  } else if (hour < 18) {
    return "Bikal";
  } else if (hour < 20) {
    return "Sondha";
  } else {
    return "Raat"
  }
}

function fmtHour(hour) {
  return `0${hour % 12 || 12}`.substr(-2);
}
function fmtMinutes(minutes) {
  return `0${minutes}`.substr(-2);
}

var input = document.getElementById("in");
var output = document.getElementById("out");

function formatOutput() {
   const date = new Date("01 Jan 1970 " + input.value);
   const hour = date.getHours();
   const min = date.getMinutes();
   output.innerText = `${fmtHour(hour)}:${fmtMinutes(min)} ${fmtPeriod(hour)}`
}

input.addEventListener('change', formatOutput);

input.value = `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`;
formatOutput();
```

```css
#out { font-family: monospace }
```

```html
<input id="in" type="time">
<span id="out"></span>
```

Of course, greater minds than mine have put in a lot of time an energy to solve this kind of problem. I'd recommend you take a loot at the standard [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) method. It may not ***exactly*** fit your requirements, but it's usually close enough to satisfy most users and will take care of all the more complicated edge cases that it's hard for a single developer to catch:

```js
const outputs = ['en-US', 'bn', 'bn-u-hc-h24'];

var input = document.getElementById("in");

function formatOutput() {
  const date = new Date(`01 Jan 1970 ${input.value}`);
  outputs.forEach(id => {
    const output = document.getElementById(id);
    output.innerText = date.toLocaleTimeString(id);
  });
}

input.addEventListener('change', formatOutput);

input.value = `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`;
formatOutput();
```

```css
span {
  font-family: monospace;
}

span::after {
  content: attr(id);
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<input id="in" type="time"><br>
<span id="en-US"></span><br>
<span id="bn"></span><br>
<span id="bn-u-hc-h24"></span><br>
```

If you're comfortable with managing npm packages, you could also take a look at something like [`date-and-time`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time) (*[try in RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/ry6m2absr3vv)*):

```
var date = require("date-and-time");

let now = new Date();
date.locale('bn');
date.format(now, 'HH:mm A');
// 16:33 দুপুর
```

Again, this might not be the ***exact*** result you want, but it's probably a lot easier and less error-prone than trying to implement the equivalent logic yourself.

Comment: Maybe, I was unable to make it clear. Actually, I am expecting something like this: The current time should appear like: (02:44:53 Raat) instead of (02:44:53 AM).                                     Edit: I'm too close to my answer. I just need to change the last two lines so that I can only get only one value at a time.

Comment: @KBTonmoy I've restructured my answer so you can hopefully get a clearer idea of what's going on. I've also tried to provide some more suggestions on how you could perhaps approach this problem differently.

Comment: You are awesome. I need another favor. Can you please change the input field with only Document.write syntax? I want to use the script in Adobe Flash actionscript.

Comment: @KBTonmoy The demo would not really work in that case, but all you'd really have to do in your code is replace `output.innerText = ...;` with `document.write(...);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getHourName(hour){
if(hour > 11 && hour < 16){
   return "Dupur"
}
if(hour > 15 && hour < 18){
   return "Bikal"
}
if(hour > 17 && hour < 20){
   return "Sondha"
}
if(hour > 19 || hour < 6){
   return "Raat"
}
if(hour > 5 && hour < 12){
   return "Sokal"
}
}

Array.from({ length: 24 }).forEach((_, hour) => {
  console.log(`${hour}:00-${hour}:59 ${getHourName(hour)}`);
});
```

Comment: `hour => 20 && hour <= 5` will fail for 12AM-5AM

Comment: I was expecting "Raat" in the current time (02:38:52). but it returned "Dupur"

Comment: Okay, fixed it. Sorry for my mistake :)

Comment: Maybe it needs another change. Can you please check the 2nd line?

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter alternative with a lookup array :

```js
function format(date) { 
   var arr = ['Sokal', 'Sokal', 'Sokal', 'Dupur', 'Dupur', 'Bikal', 'Sondha'];
   return date.toJSON().slice(11, 19) + ' ' + (arr[date.getUTCHours() - 6 >> 1] || 'Raat');
}

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++)
   console.log( format( new Date('0 ' + i + ':0Z') ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript Libary MomentJs (https://momentjs.com/).

MomentJS has multiple locale support, for example Bengali.

```
moment.locale();         // bn
moment().format('LT');   // রাত ৯:৫৮ সময়
moment().format('LTS');  // রাত ৯:৫৮:৩৪ সময়
moment().format('L');    // ২৪/০৪/২০১৯
moment().format('l');    // ২৪/৪/২০১৯
moment().format('LL');   // ২৪ এপ্রিল ২০১৯
moment().format('ll');   // ২৪ এপ্র ২০১৯
moment().format('LLL');  // ২৪ এপ্রিল ২০১৯, রাত ৯:৫৮ সময়
moment().format('lll');  // ২৪ এপ্র ২০১৯, রাত ৯:৫৮ সময়
moment().format('LLLL'); // বুধবার, ২৪ এপ্রিল ২০১৯, রাত ৯:৫৮ সময়
moment().format('llll'); // বুধ, ২৪ এপ্র ২০১৯, রাত ৯:৫৮ সময়
```

If you using a package manager like npm it is very easy to integrate momentJS in your application.

For example:
    npm install moment --save   # npm

Or other package managers:

```
yarn add moment             # Yarn
Install-Package Moment.js   # NuGet
spm install moment --save   # spm
meteor add momentjs:moment  # meteor
bower install moment --save # bower (deprecated)
```

Example usage in Node.js:

```
npm install moment
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();
```

Example usage in Browser:

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
```

Additional there are much more options to handle dates with the momentJs framework. Check it out: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Actually, I want to run the script in Adobe Flash Actionscript. I found no way to integrate Momentjs in a Flash file. By the way, It surely will help me in the future.